# Set base path for all the images in by react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am basically building a MERNy app and I want to fetch images saved on my back-end server and show it on the front-end.

My question is, how can I set the base path of my server for all the images that I fetch on my website like I can set `Axios` `baseUrl`. Because right now I add this to my src tag: `http://localhost:5000/images/myImage.jpeg`. How can I make it so that I add only `/images/myImage.jpg` and let it fetch from the server? Because whenever I deploy my back-end server I will have to change all the occurrences of `localhost` with my domain.

Comment: I think you need to introduce the constant.js into you application. like const baseURL = "http://localhost:5000/". When you are fetching the data it should be `{baseURL}images/myImage.jpeg`. Let say in future you change the server or port in that case you only need to take care is constant baseURL. Rest will automatically configure.

Comment: One more thing you can do is, send complete url from the backed. In this you need to create the combination of the port and localhost with respect to environment like production or local when you are binding the data just loop through it or you can create the one helper that will take care the same. Hope this will help you and give clarity on same

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks! I am already using constant.js but never thought of this LOL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Reverse Proxy` to abstract the image path. This way you can have three servers running behind a single domain.

- **Express** - is the API server for all your Ajax request. When a request is sent into `MyDomain.com/api` it will be redirected internally to `API_SERVER_INTERNAL_HOST:3000/`
- **Web Server (Images)** - it another Web Server that serves static files but its files will be the images the user uploaded. When a request is sent into `MyDomain.com/images` it will be redirected internally to `API_SERVER_INTERNAL_HOST:3001/`
- **Web Server (React)** - is a Web Server that serves static files (HTML, CSS, js, fonts, images, etc..) that build your app.

```
                                       /api      :3000 +---------------------+
                                     +---------------->+       Express       |
                                     |                 +---------------------+
                                     |
MyDomain.com      +---------------+  |  /        :8080 +---------------------+
+-----------------+ Proxy (Nginx) +------------------->+  Web Server (React) |
                  +---------------+  |                 +---------------------+
                                     |
                                     | /images   :3001 +---------------------+
                                     +---------------->+  Web Server (Images)|
                                                       +---------------------+
```

This setup is varied flexible and if in the future you will like to use 3rd party Web Server for hosting images you can just change the proxy config.

See the following for getting started with Nginx reverse proxy setup: https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-plus-as-an-api-gateway-part-1/

In addition:
you can use [MinIO](https://min.io/) as the Images Web Server. MinIO uses the same interface as `S3` and is really nice if you need to manage a Static files Web Server (the express app will use the MiniIO API to upload the user image to the Web Server)

Comment: Thanks, it is very informative but I have no prior knowledge of NGINX, would it be easy for me to go with me this approach? Also I don't know if you got me right or not, I am asking about how can I set the base domain name for fetching images on the front-end so that I don't have to change the domain name if I change my image server in future.